# JavaScript & jQuery: go to next loop iteration when animation is done

Tags: javascript, jquery

I expect that the below code will change the images on the slider. When the last image will be reached, it's required to restart the slideshow from the fist image and so on to infinity.

```
function launchSlider(){
  for (let i = 0; i<imagesCount; i++) {
    console.log(i);
    // The cross fading
    $allSliderImages.eq(i).fadeOut(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, 'swing'); 
    $allSliderImages.eq(i+1).fadeIn(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, 'swing');  

    // when the next image will be last in jQuery selection, we need to reset the counter
    // (in the entry to next iteration will be: i = -1 + 1 = 0)
    if (i === imagesCount - 1) {
      i = -1;
    }
  }
}
```

In this solution, it's go to next iteration before the animation complete, thus it's performs the multiple iterations per second. Of course, the browser is freeze.

How I can to go to the next iteration when crossfading animation will complete?

Comment: Check out the `complete` callback at http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

Answer (score 1):

You can not just use a `for`, that is synchronize code. You may use a callback-chain.The code is like:

```
let i = 0;
let j = 1;
var temp = function () {
    $allSliderImages.eq(i).fadeOut(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, () => {
    });
    $allSliderImages.eq(j).fadeIn(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, () => {
        if (i == imagesCount - 1) {
            i = 0
        }
        i++;
        j++
        temp();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with a solution

```
function launchSlider(){
  var i = 0;
  while( i < imagesCount) {

    // The cross fading
    $allSliderImages.eq(i).fadeOut(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, 'swing'); 
    $allSliderImages.eq(i+1).fadeIn(CROSS_FADING_DURATION, 'swing');  

    if (i === imagesCount - 1) {
      i = 0;
    } else {
      i++;
    }
  }
}
```

Check the value of `i` each time, if `i` value matches with imageCount length, then reset `i`  value to 0.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I am sorry, but this solution don't solving the problem: same as in my one, it goes to next iteration before animation done. So, it also cause the freeze because of great number of iterations per second.